# Make CSS menu items and title expand to correct width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, formatting

I am stuck trying to **expand menu items to full width**. For some reason they are indented..
**Also if I expand the menu name with more characters**, it messes up the formatting. I'm trying to make it expand automatically, but if I remove the 'width' property it becomes messed up.

Thanks!

**Fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/n877s/5/**

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
    <span>username</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

​

CSS

```
  .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
  /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 140%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    /* Styles */
    background: black;
    border-radius: inherit;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    list-style: none;

    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 15px;
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent;    
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 13px;
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) transparent;    
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8aa8bd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}


.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li i {
    float: right;
    color: inherit;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:first-of-type a {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}

/* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:hover a {
    background: #f3f8f8;
}

/* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* No CSS3 support */

.no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1; /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
    pointer-events: auto; /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: For the width problem if you take longer text you can use the following inside the .wrapper-dropdown-3 class:     min-width: 55px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right:35px; Note that it is not supported by IE6; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp

Comment: Thanks @Rsauxil, but still same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what u need. Changed just a few things like left padding from dropdown class (spacing fix), changed width to auto on `.wrapper-dropdown-3`, and added some spacing around carret.

http://jsfiddle.net/n877s/8/

I added dummy text in button,just for testing purposes, and it works well.

Comment: Thank you so much @Aleksandar. That works great. I have really been struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is caused by `UL`s default left padding (or in any browsers padding), it´s 40px. So, set

```
 .wrapper-dropdown-3 {margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;}
```

If you have longer items in submenu and don't want set the `width`, you can force one-line items using

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @panther, I entered the code you suggested. Still having problems unfortunately. Is there a way I could make the menu title have a minimum width, but also expand to fit the text?  http://jsfiddle.net/n877s/6/

Comment: Use `min-width` instead of `width`. In this case it should be `.wrapper-dropdown-3 {min-width: 85px; padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px}` - higher right padding is because of the arrow.